# New to SQL, having trouble with table with two IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a DB of scores over the course of a season and I am having trouble with a query to return the season results for a given team. Here is a snapshot of the table involved:

```
Teams (tid, team_name)
Games (home_team_id, road_team_id, game_date, home_score, road_score)
```

What would the SQL look like to return all games where home_team_id or road_team_id is 1 and include the team_name of the opponent?

Comment: Well, it would start with a `select` statement.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clearly stated in question, but I guess your main confusion is on how to get `team_name` from both `home_team_id` and `road_team_id`. You can do twice `INNER JOIN` for that purpose, for example :

```
select 
    g.*
    , home.team_name as home_team_name
    , road.team_name as road_team_name
from Games g
    inner join Teams home on home.tid = g.home_team_id
    inner join Teams road on road.tid = g.road_team_id
where g.home_team_id = 1
    or g.road_team_id = 1
```